# Send, but not receive email

Tags: 12.04, webserver, mail-server

I followed the tutorial:

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3

To configure my Ubuntu 12.04 VPS server, the mail server sending this email only but do not receive any email provider.

What might be happening?

/etc/postfix/main.cf
http://pastebin.com/CXM215vk

/etc/postfix/master.cf
http://pastebin.com/zFVskBTx

mailq:

```
Mail queue is empty
```

telnet mail.techmall.com.br 25

```
root@server:~# telnet mail.techmall.com.br 25
Trying 198.199.65.44...
Connected to techmall.com.br.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.techmall.com.br ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

iptables -L
http://pastebin.com/jz5XjLN2

Thanks

Comment: Please check your first link. It does not appear to be true.

Comment: Which link? All are working for me. thank you

Comment: this link is coming as 404 error ..... http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-se...ot-ispconfig-3

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to first rely on the OFFICIAL Documentation rather than on other tutorials. You should first check out the official documentation for the article and then if you don't understand the things that those people are doing, you should search for some other articles. Here is the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MailServer) to that article. You can read that article and then ask any questions here if you don't understand any part of it.